# Minecraft Skin Overlay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I painted my own Minecraft skin in paint in 64*64 pixel in  .png. But my Minecraft Launcher does not show them when I add them. What can I do to make him show my Overlays?
(Yes, I put anything in skincustumisation at on)

Comment: did you set it as your skin?

Answer (score 1):

If your using a resource pack then be sure to add the skin in the `resourcepack\assets\minecraft\textures\entity\` folder as ether `alex.png` or `steve.png`.

To change skin, however, you need to log in to [Minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net) and you can change your skin in your profile, just by uploading the image.

Be sure you have the correct layout in your image:
Basic steve skin:
[image: steve]

My skin for comparison(the colorful parts are overlays):
[image: SemlanBakelsen]